# Keep getting NoReverseMatch error in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to do a update function for this form. The template page displays properly, but once i click submit button, i keep getting the NoReverseMatch error: Reverse for **'update_page'** with keyword arguments **'{'title': ''}'** not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: **['wiki/(?P[^/]+)/update$']**
The project does not have models, as per assignment. The db is basically a folder in the same directory. And the files in this folder are being managed through the **list_entries(), save_entry() and get_entry()** functions in the **util.py**.

urls:

```
app_name = "entries"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("newpage", views.newpage, name="newpage"),
    path("<str:title>", views.open_page, name="open_page"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search_query"),
    path("<str:title>/update", views.update_page, name="update_page"),
    path("random/", views.random_page, name="random_page"),
    path("<str:title>/deleted", views.del_page, name="del_page")

]
```

My views code:

```
def update_page(request, title):
entered_content = util.get_entry(title)
form_dict = {'form_title': title, 'form_content': entered_content}

if request.method == "POST":
    form = NewPageForm(request.POST or None, initial=form_dict)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        
        title = form.cleaned_data[title]
        updated_content = form.cleaned_data['form_content']
        util.save_entry(title, updated_content)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entries:open_page", args=(title), ))
    else: 
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/updatepage.html", {
            "form": form
        })

return render(request, "encyclopedia/updatepage.html", {
    "form": NewPageForm(request.POST or None, initial=form_dict),
    "titles": title,        
})
```

The template:

```
{% block body %}

<h2>Update the {{titles}} entry:</h2>

<form action="{% url 'entries:update_page' title=titles %}" method="post">
    
    {% csrf_token %}    
    {{ form.form_content}}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<form method="GET" action="{% url 'entries:del_page' title=titles %}" >
<button type = "submit" >Delete Entry</button>
</form>

<a href = "{% url 'entries:index' %}">View Entries</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: titles variable is not set in context and not rendered in template hence error

Answer (score -1):

Could you try removing str from the path, as str according to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/), matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator, '/'. This is the default if a converter isn’t included in the expression.

```
app_name = "entries"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("newpage", views.newpage, name="newpage"),
    path("title/", views.open_page, name="open_page"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search_query"),
    path("title/update", views.update_page, name="update_page"),
    path("random/", views.random_page, name="random_page"),
    path("title/deleted", views.del_page, name="del_page")

]
```

Comment: Thank you @Hridyesh, it didnt work though. I v got this error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/Test%202/update
Using the URLconf defined in wiki.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
The current path, wiki/Test 2/update, didn't match any of these. Btw, the <str:.. works well for other functions, including the "delete" option on the same template that gives me the initial error described above.